# Best way to handle ownership of resource

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am looking for a nice and generic way to check if current logged user is the owner of the resource he is trying to **show** / **update** / **delete** / ...

In the application, every resource linked to a user has a field `user_id` matching the ID of the user that created it.

Is there a way to do this with a `Plug`, something that would look like :

```
  plug :owner_check when action in [:show]

  def show(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
    provisioned_device = Devices.get_provisioned_device!(id)
    render(conn, "show.html", provisioned_device: provisioned_device)
  end
```

If logged user is owner, render the `show.html` page and if not, redirect to an error page.

So I can use it for all resources that have a `user_id` field?

Currenly I use this logic to check if the user is authenticated but I can't find a way to update it to check ownership.

```
  def user_check(%Plug.Conn{assigns: %{current_user: nil}} = conn, _opts) do
    need_login(conn)
  end

  def user_check(conn, _opts), do: conn

  defp need_login(conn) do
    conn
    |> put_session(:request_path, current_path(conn))
    |> put_flash(:error, "You need to log in to view this page")
    |> redirect(to: Routes.session_path(conn, :new))
    |> halt()
  end
```

Comment: this question seems to be too open ended and related more to database design than to elixir or phoenix. In your case I would just create a separate plug for role checking and use it where you need it, also don't forget that you can send parameters to plug.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy to check if the user is authenticated in a plug because that's going to look the same for most of your requests. It's a lot harder to tell if a user owns a resource before the request gets routed to your controller because you can't tell from the params alone who the owner should be.

If you really wanted to make it a plug, you could have a load resource/check ownership plug that takes a schema in the opts and, when the action is one that requires an existing resource, loads the resource by an id from the params and checks that user_id matches the currently signed in user. You could then plug it in a controller, passing in the appropriate schema for that controller.

It might be easier, though, to just check it in your controllers.